# parsing a csv datafile in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a data file in csv format that consists of Pokemon names and statistics. I want to read it into python as a matrix. The column headers are the first row of the data table, columns are separated by commas and rows are seperated by "\n"

```
    pokedex_file = 'pokedex_basic.csv'
    with open(pokedex_file, 'r') as f:
        raw_pd = f.read()
```

is the ecode I have but I am crashing my memory when using line.strip()? Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show your complete code? Where are you using `line.strip()`

Comment: You're not giving us enough code. Where are you defining "line?" There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a package called csv which makes it very easy to parse csv files.
If your CSV file has headers, like

```
Name,Type
Charizard,Fire/Dragon
Pikachu,Electric
```

then you can use the DictReader tool from csv to parse your file.

```
import csv
with open('pokemon.csv', 'r') as pokedex:
  reader = csv.DictReader(pokedex)
  for line in reader: # line is a dict to represent this line of data
      print(line)
      current_name = line['Name']
      current_type = line['Type']
      print("The pokemon {:s} has type {:s}".format(current_name, current_type))
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'Charizard', 'Type': 'Fire/Dragon'}
The pokemon Charizard has type Fire/Dragon
{'Name': 'Pikachu', 'Type': 'Electric'}
The pokemon Pikachu has type Electric
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how it is stored, you may be able to read it using dictReader.

```
import csv
with open('/path-name.csv', 'r') as input:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input)
    for dataDict in reader:
        # do stuff with dataDict
        stats = dataDict['pokemon_name']
```

Comment: That's what I though, an ordered dictionary gets my output close and might work, but I need to find  the mean and std on columns and numpy didnt help??

Comment: @RobertDwyer Could you please upload ALL your code and give a sample of your data when opened in Notepad/TextEdit? I might be able to give you a better idea of how to go forward then.

Comment: I'd llove to but computer died and l left charger at work. Sorry.. You're right Dictreader has to b the way to go. Everything I read about parsing csv includes Dictreader.

Comment: That is usually the highest recommended. Please update this question whenever you can, or you might be downvoted a lot more than once.